# Changing a synchronous method to async

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I've googled around a lot and read different noob tutorials, but I don't think I understand what the proper thing to do is.  Basically there is existing code that is synchronous that does something if the server is up and running.  Sometimes, very rarely, the server takes longer to come up so I wanted to wrap it in some retry logic.  I built a completely stupid console app to try to understand how async and await work a little bit and came up with this:

```
    private static int counter = 0;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DoIt();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static bool LongTask()
    {
        if (counter == 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("finally true");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            return true;
        }
        counter++;
        Console.WriteLine("false");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        return false;
    }

    public static Task<bool> WrapperLongTask()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("wrapper called");
        return Task.Run(() => LongTask());            
    }

    public static async Task DoIt()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hi");
        var result = await WrapperLongTask();
        while (result != true)
        {
            result = await WrapperLongTask();
            Console.WriteLine("inside while loop");
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"outside while loop {result}");
        Console.WriteLine("bye");
    }
```

My LongTask function is representing my current function that does work that usually works the first time.  Is it ok practice to then call this method with

```
Task.Run(() => LongTask())
```

Assuming that is 'ok', then I would basically create this in my actual code for my current method `DoWork()`.

```
Task DoWorkAsync(....) {
     return Task.Run(() => DoWork()
}
```

Basically just wrapping it in a Task.Run, changing the return type to Task.  Then when I call this method later, I would do something like

```
var x = await DoWorkAsync;
// do more stuff with x
```

Is this way I should convert a previous sync method async?

### Edit

pseudo code for DoWork(string directory, CancellationToken token)

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (var file in files) {
    try {
       token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
       var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
       // check if file already exists on server, if not, upload it
    }
    catch (Exception exception) {
       // error handling
    }
}
```

Comment: What is this "does something"? Do you have to wait on results before the server does anything further? Does it call into any methods that have asynchronous equivalents? What else is the server doing? (Is this an ASP.NET web application or something else)? Depending on those the answers to those questions, particularly the last one, I might advise differently, or perhaps that you don't bother with async at all.

Comment: Could you post your "real" code, so that we could see how it might be able to be asynchronous?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer is No, you cannot convert all types of synchronous code to asynchronous simply by wrapping the operation with `Task.Run` and making the method return `Task`.

Usually, asynchronous code makes sense when the operation in consideration might invoke some IO operations (file system read/write, network or web access, database access ... etc.).

For example, if you have a method that reads some data from a file using synchronous methods like `FileStream.Read`, and then does some CPU work on the contents of such file, then you can convert your method to be asynchronous by making it invoke `FileStream.ReadAsync` instead and then asynchronously wait until `ReadAsync` is done by using the `await` keyword and then work on the contents of the file (of course you have to change the method to return `Task` and to be `async`).

The benefit in this case is that there is no thread waiting for the IO operation to complete and threads are expensive.

The benefit of not having threads waiting for IO operations to complete is very important in server applications like ASP.NET web sites where you expect a lot of simultaneous requests. However, for simple applications you might not want to bother with asynchronous code in the first place.

You can use `Task.Run` if you want to run multiple CPU intensive operations on multiple CPU cores.

For example, if you have 4 CPU cores, it makes sense to create 4 tasks via `Task.Run` to process some data. Consider the previous example, after you asynchronously wait for `ReadAsync` to complete, you can split the result of the read to 4 parts (assuming that the data is relatively large), and create 4 tasks via `Task.Run`, each will handle one part of the results. You can then asynchronously wait for the 4 tasks to complete using `Task.WhenAll`.

Comment: If you're doing CPU bound work on large sequences it makes more sense to use `Parallel.ForEach` than tasks. It'll do input partitioning and load balancing way better than "split sequence into N parts"

Comment: That's right. I used `Task.Run` because I wanted to give OP an example of when it can be used. Please note also that (AFAIK) you cannot asynchronously wait for `Parallel.ForEach` to complete. It blocks the current thread until all operations are complete.