# How to async MD5 Calculate? C#

Tags: c#, .net, hash

How can i use Calculate MD5 Hash as Async?

I have this code:

```
static string CalculateMD5(string filename)
{
    using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
    {
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
        {
            var hash = md5.ComputeHash(stream);
            return BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "").ToUpperInvariant();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to hash a file of 1GB and then it freezes my app for 20 sec.

Comment: What have you tried to make this work asynchronously? Show your attempt(s).

Comment: make it a task and await it if you need

Comment: Yes but i dont understand Task and how make that ;v I learn somthing but any result ;v

Comment: There are countless examples of, threads, async out there, one will make sense to you - SO is specifically not about recommending tutorials

Comment: static async Task<string> CalculateMD5(string filename)
        {
            using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
            {
                using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
                {
                    var hash = md5.ComputeHash(stream);
                    return BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "").ToUpperInvariant();
                }
            }
        }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing a synchronous method to async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34645667/changing-a-synchronous-method-to-async)

Comment: Just to make clear, turning the operation asynchronous might help with the app freezing but doesn't make it run any faster. Also you have to adapt the rest of the app so that it reacts to when the operation is finished.

Comment: Yes i know but i dont wanna have this freeze ;v

Comment: As you seem to be new, I would adivse towards using the BackgroundWorker. It is not something you want to be caught using in producive code, but it is good for you first few steps in Multitasking. Once you learned how to deal with all the Idiosyncracies of Multitasking (Race Conditions, UI class Thread association, Exception handling), you can switch to the more advanced stuff like Tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are reading from a file you can use IO-bound asynchronicity. Unfortunarely neither the File class nor the MD5 class support it out of the box. But it can be manually done:

```
static async Task<string> CalculateMD5Async(string filename)
{
  using (var md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create())
  {
    using (var stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 4096, true)) // true means use IO async operations
    {
      byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
      int bytesRead;
      do
      {
        bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 4096);
        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
          md5.TransformBlock(buffer, 0, bytesRead, null, 0);
        }
      } while (bytesRead > 0);

      md5.TransformFinalBlock(buffer, 0, 0);
      return BitConverter.ToString(md5.hash).Replace("-", "").ToUpperInvariant();
    }
  }
```

For performance reasons you may want to increase the buffer size.

Comment: This method will require the `async` modifier. Also, you can replace the `do` loop with: `while ((bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)`

Comment: @glenebob Thanks for pointing out that I forgot the async modifier.

Comment: ```md5.hash``` in the last line should be ```md5.Hash```  (```return BitConverter.ToString(md5.hash).Replace("-", "").ToUpperInvariant();```)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 private async void CalculateMd5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var filePath = "Path/to/your/file";
        var md5hash = await CalculateMd5ForFileAsync(filePath);
    }

    private Task<string> CalculateMd5ForFileAsync(string filePath)
    {
        return new Task<string>(() => ComputeMd5HashForFile(filePath));
    }

    private string ComputeMd5HashForFile(string filePath)
    {
        using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
        {
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
            {
                var hash = md5.ComputeHash(stream);
                return BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "").ToUpperInvariant();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the point? You can do async IO, so there is no need to wrap sync IO in a CPU-bound task.

Comment: This is the original code, just wrapped in a Task. The point was to show how to use async/await!

Comment: Hashing is a CPU intensive process. It makes sense to do it on a background thread. There's also no ComputeHashAsync(), so to use async IO, you'd need to write a little more code.

Comment: Thanks for help but i dont know why i this return System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String]

Comment: @glenebob I would assume that it's still much faster than IO access.

Comment: @ckuri, it's almost certainly faster than IO access, but I still would not want to hash a gigabyte of data on the UI thread, no matter its source.

Comment: @Famous, it returns a Task so that it can be awaited.

Comment: @IvanSyrotiuk Currently the code is not working as you instantiate a task, but do not start it. Instead of `new Task` (which should never be used) `Task.Run` should be used.

Comment: @glenebob Hmm, I understand. Maybe a combined approach would be better?

Comment: @ckuri, yes, exactly. An async method doing async IO and MD5, which is called via `Task.Run(async () => ...)`.

Comment: @glenebob there is a ComputeHashAsync available now in .NET 5+ (Nov 2020).    See my answer on this duplicate question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76609381/50356https://stackoverflow.com/a/76609381/50356https://stackoverflow.com/a/76609381/50356

Answer (score 1):

As of .NET 5 (Nov 2020), there is a `ComputeHashAsync` available.

```cs
async Task<byte[]> ComputeFileHash(string filename)
{
    byte[] hash;
    using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(filename))
        hash = await MD5.Create().ComputeHashAsync(fs);
    return hash;
}
```